# how do you convert an ip address to a domain name in Python?

Tags: python

I'm creating a website with Python but I don't know how to convert an ip address to a domain name with python.How do you do it?

Comment: [`resolvedIP = socket.gethostbyaddr(IPAddress)`](http://www.ehow.com/how_8671013_resolve-ip-python.html)?

Comment: This question is far too broad to answer. What IP Address are you talking about, What do you mean by Domain name, are you trying to register your website so you have a domain name? Websites generally don't use IP addresses at all so this question makes no sense in it's current form.

Answer (score 1):

A Domain resolve to an Ip. An Ip mustn't resolve to an Domain. You need support of reverse dns.

You can achieve this with `dnspython`

```
from dns import resolver,reversename
addr=reversename.from_address("192.168.0.1")
str(resolver.query(addr,"PTR")[0])
```

http://spareclockcycles.org/2010/04/13/reverse-dns-lookups-with-dnspython/